# Jsoup Select Exclude (strong tag inside div)

Tags: html, jsoup

I have a html Code like this:

```
<div class="address">
    <strong>Max Mustermann  </strong>             
    <br>Secondstreet 12          
    <br>1234 New York     
    <br>                      
    <br>                     
    <br>                     
</div>
```

Here is my Code:

```
    html = html.replace("<br>", "br34k");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements divs = doc.select("div.address");

    StringBuilder divResult = new StringBuilder();
    for (Element div : divs) {
        divResult.append(div.text());
    }
    String result = divResult.toString();

    result = completeResults.replace("br34k", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    System.out.println(result);
```

With this the output looks like:

```
06-18 20:00:30.290: I/System.out(623): Cafe Palio 
06-18 20:00:30.290: I/System.out(623): Marktplatz 1 
06-18 20:00:30.290: I/System.out(623): 79312 Emmendingen 
06-18 20:00:30.290: I/System.out(623):  
06-18 20:00:30.290: I/System.out(623):  
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623): Domino Stüble 
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623): Markgrafenstr. 57 
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623): 79312 Emmendingen 
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623):  
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623):  
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623): Pizza Boxx 
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623): Am Elzdamm 66 
06-18 20:00:30.300: I/System.out(623): 79312 Emmendingen
```

But what i need is a String without the Name such as:

Marktplatz 1
79312 Emmendingen

Markgrafenstr. 57
79312 Emmendingen

and so on..

Comment: Rippler2k5 Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize the code around `String`, if you want.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(content);
    String text = document.select(".address").text();
    String title = document.select(".address strong").text();
    String output = text.replaceFirst(title, "").trim();
    System.out.println(output);
```

> updated the answer to reflect the updated question

This code works if you have multiple `<div>`'s with `class="address"`

```
Elements elements = document.select(".address");
    for (Iterator<Element> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Element element = iterator.next();
        String text = element.text();
        String title = element.select("strong").text();
        String output = text.replaceFirst(title, "").trim();
        System.out.println(output);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easiest if your HTML markup were correct :

```
<div class="address">
    <strong id="name">Max Mustermann  </strong>             
    <span id="address-part-one">Secondstreet 12</span>          
    <span id="address-part-two">1234 New York</span>                         
</div>
```

You don't need `br` tag here, you should use CSS instead. Retrieve the address tags content separately then concatenate it.